# Converting in batch into 8 unsigned bit format using GDAL?

Tags: gdal

Could you please correct my batch command?

I had 100 img images which need to be converted into 8 unsigned bit format for further use in TIMESAT.

`mkdir test
for %%f in (*.img) do gdal_translate -of ENVI -scale -1 1 1 255 -a_nodata 0 -co INTERLEAVE=BSQ "%%f" test/%%f.dat`

Comment: Would you be able to **edit** your question to say what happens when you run your code, please?  Our volunteers are usually happy to try and help with code when people show what they have tried and precisely where they are stuck but not to be used as a code writing/debugging service.

Comment: What happens when you run your command on a single .img file?

Comment: When I run that command on a image, it does what you'd expect it to do. The output naming scheme is a bit unfortunate, as you'll end up with files that are named .img.dat which is somewhat confusing, but apart from that it appears to be working.

Comment: The result is still 32 bit floating file format. I'm expected to have an unsigned 8 bit file.

Comment: There is an **edit** button beneath your question that will enable you to update it with that information.  Think of comments as being temporary - they may or may not be read by potential answerers.

Answer (score 2):

You're expecting a 8-bit file, but you aren't exactly telling gdal that you want that. You need to add '-ot Byte'. See [this help page](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html) for more info.

Your command becomes:

```
for %%f in (*.img) do gdal_translate -ot Byte -of ENVI -scale -1 1 1 255 -a_nodata 0 -co INTERLEAVE=BSQ "%%f" test/%%f.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want another file extension, you have to tweak the variable like this way:

```
for %%N in (D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25\*.tif) DO gdal_translate -of vrt -expand rgba %%N D:\Karten\gdal\gdal2tiles\NL25\%%~nN.vrt
```

See http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html for details on that.