# Using GDAL in Windows with command longer than 8191 characters

Tags: gdal, windows

I have a large number of files, over 7000. I need to run GDAL commands on those files, but I am limited by 8191 characters in Windows. Is there any way to avoid this limitation?

Comment: You can use a loop, as described in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134656/converting-in-batch-into-8-unsigned-bit-format-using-gdal/134673#134673 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162746/gdal2tiles-and-qgis/162778#162778

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first you create a vrt with all your files, then you use this vrt as input of your other tools.

Of course, building vrt will also be limited in number of characters, but :

- you can use wildcard *, e.g `gdalbuildvrt output.vrt /path/to/input/example*.tif`
- you can use a text file with all the names of your input files in it (onefile per line), using `gdalbuildvrt output.vrt -input_file_list my_list.txt`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what GDAL command you want to perform but using optfile as documented in http://www.gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html may come to your rescue.

> --optfile file
>
> Read the named file and substitute the contents into the command line options list. Lines beginning with # will be ignored. Multi-word
>   arguments may be kept together with double quotes.