# The Difference of clipping Images based on Gdalwarp and QGIS software?

Tags: gdal

I clipped same MODIS image by using QGIS and GDAL based on same shapefile.

Fig.1 and Fig.2 are clipped using QGIS software and GDAL coding, Fig.3 and Fig.4 are image geolocation of original image(upper red box) and clipped image(bottom red box) in QGIS and GDAL.

We can see, from Fig.3, the upper left geolocation of clipped image(bottom red box) and original image(upper red box) in QGIS are same.However,geolocation of  GDAL-clipped result(Fig.4) is on the contrary. QGIS-clipped image include some background pixels outside of shapefile boundary(Fig. 1 compared to Fig. 2).

I want to get the result as Fig.2 using GDAL or QGIS.

Fig.5 is clipping command in GDAL,Fig.6 is clipping command in QGIS.
Why exits result difference?

[image]

```
              Fig.1
```

[image]

```
              Fig.2
```

[image]

```
              Fig.3
```

[image]

```
              Fig.4
```

[image]

```
              Fig.5
```

[image]

```
              Fig.6
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the input dialogue of the clip command in QGIS, and the GDAL command line you used? If you clip by another layer, the extent and CRS of that too, and the corner points of the source image.

Comment: Yeah,@AndreJ your answer reminds me to know maybe -crop_to_cutline contributes to the difference.However, what I should handling in QGIS software.

Comment: In QGIS, you can click on the yellow pencil icon, and add `-crop to cutline` manually to the command. QGIS is just a wrapper around GDAL, and it does not include **all** options in the dialogue.

Comment: Yeah,I have made it.Thanks,you are right.But I want to batch clipping tens of images,I cannot to modify the command when I click Batch mode in QGIS. So, can I have to achieve the goal in GDAL rather than in QGIS?

Comment: You can create a looping batch file for GDAL, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56842/how-to-clip-raster-by-multiple-polygons-in-multi-rasters/150680#150680 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53929/having-problems-creating-vrt-in-qgis-from-png-files/53945#53945 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134656/converting-in-batch-into-8-unsigned-bit-format-using-gdal/134673#134673 for the syntax

Comment: BTW you can also do batch processing and crop to cutline within processing.

Comment: Yeah,@AndreJ have solved my question.And My second question in question's comments is to find a way to solve the batching processing.Now,I find another way to achieve the goal using bat file in OSGeo4W Shell rather than in QGIS software.